# Pandas re.compile function – IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python, pandas

This code for `pandas` searches for `r"\d+X|X\d+"` for each cell in a DataFrame column. 
If it finds `"X"` it changes it into `"x"`.

```
match = re.compile(r"\d+X|X\d+", flags=re.IGNORECASE)

def f(value):
    f2 = lambda x: match.findall(x)[0] if len(match.findall(x)) > 0 else ""

    leverage = f2(value)

    if leverage[0].replace("X","x") == "x":
        leverage = "".join(leverage[1:])+leverage[0].replace("X","x")

    #Do other stuff here for var
    return var

df["description"] = df["name"].map(lambda x:f(x))
```

---

Problem: If no `"x"` or `"X"` is found in the cell in column `"name"`, it gives the error:

```
if leverage[0].replace("X","x") == "x":
IndexError: string index out of range
```

How can I circumvent this problem for strings that doesn't contain any of these characters?

---

Example DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(["LONG APPLE X5 C", "SHORT APPLE C"], columns=["name"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just filter the df first using [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) before calling your func:

```
df["description"] = df.loc[df['name'].str.contains('x', case=False), 'name'].map(lambda x:f(x))
```

So the mask returns this:

```
In [17]:
df.loc[df['name'].str.contains('x', case=False), 'name']

Out[17]:
0    LONG APPLE X5 C
Name: name, dtype: object
```

You can just add a check in your func if you don't want to mask your df:

```
def f(value):
    if 'x' not in value.lower():
        print('not in')
        # do whatever you want here
```

Comment: If possible I would prefer a solution directly in the function.

Comment: I've updated my answer but depending on the number of duff values, masking first may be more performant